# RxJs and Typescript. TS2307: Cannot find module '@reactivex/rxjs'

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I got a problem with typescript and RxJs v5.

### Please Look the UPDATE sections.

I did `yarn add @reactivex/rxjs` (also `yarn add rxjs`) and on my index.ts did `import Rx from '@reactivex/rxjs';` and got this error: [image: VSCode Error]

Also, if I run `node ./node_modules/.bin/tsc` I got this error back too `error TS2307: Cannot find module '@reactivex/rxjs'.`

### UPDATE

Also doing

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
```

throws the *same* error
[image].

### UPDATE 2

Well this seems to be more related to TS itself than to RxJS.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es2015",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressExcessPropertyErrors": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "lib": [
        "es2015",
        "dom"
    ]
}
```

Having this ^ configuration seems to fix the VSCode issues, but running `tsc` against `src/index.ts` doesn't work

```
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(69,60): error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Comment: I suspect the reason is down to the tooling. The `package.json` is a little unusual, with `"main": "index.js"` and `"typings": "./dist/cjs/Rx.d.ts"`. It's possible the tools are not using the `typings` entry. Anyway, if you are using anything else with an RxJS dependency, you should install `npm install rxjs`, as that's what the other dependencies are likely to be using.

Comment: Hey Cartant, can you elaborate a little more please? I think I'm not following you here.

Comment: `@reactivex/rxjs` does not have a `.d.ts` file that that parallels the file referred to as `main` in the `package.json`; the `.d.ts` is more deeply nested. I'm guessing that could confuse some tools. And if you have other dependencies (e.g. Angular) that use `rxjs`, TypeScript will likely be unhappy, as the types in `@reactivex/rxjs` will be seen as different types. I would recommend going with Martin's answer.

Answer (score 16):

Try setting the `"moduleResolution": "node"` inside your `compileOptions` to specify module resolution strategy for TS.

`npm install rxjs --save`

and in your Typescript

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';`

That fixed it for me.

Comment: What caused that problem? It's not just about re-installing rxjs, because for Angular apps it already exists, but it gives the same error

Answer (score 5):

For me I had the error below:
*error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.*

Solution:
instead of importing:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

use:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

and you can put to the observable you want to import by separating all by comma like:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 2):

For RxJS 5 you're supposed to use:

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';
```

Or import only a specific part of the library:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

For more info see: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/#installation-and-usage

Comment: Hey Martin thanks but I already tried what's under _installation and usage_. ```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```
I got the same message as above "cannot find module rxjs/Observable"

Comment: Are you sure it's really downloaded into `./node_modules/rxjs`?

Comment: Yeah it is in there.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in a brand new 'Hello World' project in Visual Studio 2017, for which I had executed `npm install rxjs`.

Basically just had this in my `server.ts` file:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import * as http from 'http';

var port = process.env.port || 1337
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);
```

Depending on the values set for compile options `module` and `lib`, this generated the error:

```
server.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Build:Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
```

or:

```
node_modules\rxjs\Observable.d.ts(73,59): error TS2693: Build:'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

The winning combination of compile options that worked for me were:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [ "es2015" ]
  }
```

This made both errors to go away.

Comment: `"commonjs"` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
```

Or

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3)
```

Or

```
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Observable.of(1,2,3).map(x => x + '!!!'); // etc
```

All these examples can be found on the website:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

```
This is a hard nut to crack: my fix

 in package.json  dependencies confirm this code exists:

     "rxjs": "^5.5.2",


In file /node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts

//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// yeah, sure, I'm not supposed to, but I did and i worked
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';


in file node_modules/rxjs/src/tsconfig.json

    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "dist/es6",
        "lib": [ "es2016.array.include" ]
      },
      "formatCodeOptions": {
        "indentSize": 2,
        "tabSize": 2
      },
      "bazelOptions": {
        "suppressTsconfigOverrideWarnings": true
      },
      "files": [
        "src/Rx.ts"
      ]
    }

for this ng --version

    Angular CLI: 1.6.7
    Node: 8.11.1
    OS: darwin x64
    Angular: 5.2.10
    ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
    ... http, language-service, platform-browser
    ... platform-browser-dynamic, router

    @angular/cli: 1.6.7
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
    @angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
    @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.2.0
    @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
    @ngtools/webpack: 1.9.7
    @schematics/angular: 0.1.17
    typescript: 2.4.2
    webpack-dev-server: 2.11.2
    webpack: 3.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine the following scenario:

```
my-app
  |__ app.ts
```

`app.ts` file contains `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'` according to [martin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753145/5541434).

**I want to compile my `app.ts` to `app.js`**

step 1: `npm install rxjs`

- `node_modules` directory is added

```
my-app
  |__ app.ts
  |__ node_modules
          |__ rxjs
          |__ ...
```

step 2:

- **without** *tsconfig.json*:

  - step 2-1: run `tsc --target es2015 --module commonjs app`
- **with** *tsconfig.json*:

  - step 2-1: add `tsconfig.json` to `my-app` folder.

```
my-app
  |__ app.ts
  |__ tsconfig.json
  |__ node_modules
          |__ rxjs
          |__ ...
```

- - step 2-2: set following configurations to `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015"
  },
  "files": ["app.ts"]
}
```

- - step 2-3: run `tsc` not <del>`tsc app`</del>

step 3: for run compiled file, `node app.js`

Answer (score 0):

This issue came for me when I installed UUID package using npm, then I installed using yarn and it worked fine for me.