# I can't install rxjs module

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've tried installing rxjs with "npm install rxjs" but it still can't find the module after installing. I've tried installing "npm install --save rxjs-compat" as well as reinstalling and uninstalling the modules, but it still doesn't work. Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

[image]

Here's the version I'm using from the package.json file:
""rxjs": "^7.4.0","

**UPDATE**

Tried all the answers but still no luck:

Here's the code for my tsconfig file (Don't know why I can't edit the original question anymore): pastebin.com/bsv51Dmz –

**UPDATE 2**
I tried installing the version 6.5 and the errors dissapear in visual studio, but I still get them on the console when doing ng serve. Same error, can not find the module. I also tried removing node-modules and doing npm i, but no luck neither, same error happening

**UPDATE 3 SOLUTION**
So what I did was basically I went to stackblitz to find some project that had the same dependencies I was trying to use and was working, and found out they had the dependency declared as "rxjs: latest" I put that declaration on my package.json and then it started working!

Comment: Here's the code for my tsconfig file (Don't know why I can't edit the original question anymore): 

https://pastebin.com/bsv51Dmz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

So what I did was basically I went to stackblitz to find some project that had the same dependencies I was trying to use and was working, and found out they had the dependency declared as "rxjs: latest" I put that declaration on my package.json and then it started working!

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: It doesn't work neither. I tried it already and it doesn't pick it up just like the other imports.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it this way

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';
```

Or it might be something with your `compilerOptions` in your tsconfig file.

I'm looking at similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750266/rxjs-and-typescript-ts2307-cannot-find-module-reactivex-rxjs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548734/tsc-throws-ts2307-cannot-find-module-for-a-local-file)

Comment: Tried it and no luck. Tried all the answers in both links and still no luck, I'll upload the compiler options on the question. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Can you upload it somewhere, maybe github/stackblitz? Could it be somehow related with version incompatibility?

Comment: Yes will add as comment on the original question, but it's here: https://github.com/seal63/ImageReelManager/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have some types needed.

To install all Module Types (CJS/ES6/AMD/TypeScript) via npm:

- To install this library via npm version 3, use the following command:

```
     
npm install @reactivex/rxjs
```

- If you are using npm version 2 before this library has achieved a stable version, you need to specify the library version explicitly:

```
     
npm install @reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.1
```

From official documentation [HERE](https://rxjs.dev/guide/installation)

Comment: Tried it and still doesn't work, same message

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired a clean install? Remove node_modules and then run `npm i`
Also you could try and either restart your extensions host in vs code or restart vc code completely..

Comment: Tried and nothing happened, still the same error. I tried restarting visual studio and still the same. The error happens when doing ng serve as well in the console so it shouldn't be editor related I think